# ¿Uso de plantillas blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo entendido que las plantillas blades nos ayudan a simplificar ciertas cosas y a que el código se vea más limpio, por lo cual mi pregunta es la siguiente:

tengo esta estructura en mi carpeta **views**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el archivo **plantilla.blade.php** que está en la carpeta **layouts** tengo una estructura  base para todo el sitio , la cual luego extiendo en mi archivo **create.blade.php** ubicado en la carpeta **usuarios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la **section('cuerpo')** quiero ingresar un formulario , por lo cual quiero saber si es mejor hacer un **@include('componentes.formulario')**(lo cual es lo que estoy haciendo porque creo que se ve más limpio el código) o mejor pongo directamente el código del formulario en la **section('cuerpo')** o de plano da lo mismo , cabe resaltar que de las dos maneras me va a mostrar el formulario igualmente, pero que lo que quiero tener son unas buenas prácticas ,un código limpio y lo más entendible posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general es mejor práctica en Blade (Laravel) utilizar `@include` y dividir todo en la mayor cantidad de partes pequeñas y reutilizables, esto hará el código más limpio y profesional (repito, para un proyecto Laravel), pero no necesariamente lo hará más entendible. Al haber más componentes, slots, variables, datos que pasan de un lado a otro, una persona que no tenga mucha experiencia con Blade lo va a ver difícil y enredado, pero en parte eso depende también de tus convenciones de nombres.

En el ejemplo puntual del formulario, es mejor `@include` porque lo vas a necesitar (normalmente) para la creación y la edición del modelo, lo cual lo hace reutilizable.

Si deseas ver un ejemplo directamente de Laravel, revisa como son generados en el frontend los Mail en el framework: https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.7/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html

Answer (score 1):

Veo que estas trabajando con el concepto de "componentes".

Si estas trabajando con Laravel 5.4 o superior existe un elemento en blade para estos usos, llamado @component que es realmente útil para reutilizar pequeños fragmentos de código.

Su funcionamiento es muy similar al include, con algunas variaciones

Pero podrías conseguir algo similar a esto:

```
@extends('../layout.plantilla')

@section('encabezado')
@endsection

@section('cuerpo')
 @component('componentes.formulario')
 @endcomponent
@endsection

@section('pie')
@endsection
```

Incluso podrías añadir alias con Laravel 5.7 y tener:

```
@form
@endform
```

Si quisieras pasarle variables, funcionan con lo que se denominan slot

```
@component('componentes.formulario')
  @slot('var1',$var1);
  @slot('var2',$var2);
  @slot('var3',$var3);
@endcomponent
```

Si quieres estudiarlo con más detalle te dejo un link a la documentación [Components & Slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#components-and-slots)

Te dejo también este link de un articulo [How to Use Blade Component and Include Aliases](https://laravel-news.com/blade-component-include-aliases)

Sobre la cuestión de modulación, hay que tener en cuenta que una modulación en exceso a veces es igual de inconveniente que no realizar ningún tipo de modulación. Pero a veces encontrar el punto de "hasta donde modular" es algo subjetiva.

En esta cuestión en concreto, creo que es adecuado el concepto que le estas dando de "componentes".

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda. Un saludo